# Reference for table of cubes modulo $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Is there an online table with all the cubes in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ (with $m$ up to (say) $100$, at least)?

I didn't find anything googling it. Thanks.

Comment: I can easily generate such a list with Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this list: http://notes.io/w5Ji

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot, my friend